# Signature doesn't match in REST API

Tags: java, android, rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have used a code for creating a bucket on Amazon. I don't want to use Amazon SDK available as it makes my android code very heavy,therefore tryng to write REST API.

I found the code here [REST API](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2007/11/07/introduction-to-amazon-s3-with-java-and-rest.html)

I have used true keys. But I get this error

```
403
Error: AccessDenied

SignatureDoesNotMatch. The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
```

Please help.

Code

```
  public class Operation {

private javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec signingKey = null;
private javax.crypto.Mac mac = null;
private String keyId = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Operation t = new Operation();
    try {
        t.setKeyId("YourAWSAccessKeyIDHere");
        t.setKey("YourAWSSecretKeyHere");
        t.createBucket();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void createBucket() throws Exception
{
    // S3 timestamp pattern.
    String fmt = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ";
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(fmt, Locale.US);
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

    // Data needed for signature
    String method = "PUT";
    String contentMD5 = "";
    String contentType = "";
    String date = df.format(new Date()) + "GMT";
    String bucket = "/onjava";

    // Generate signature
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    buf.append(method).append("\n");
    buf.append(contentMD5).append("\n");
    buf.append(contentType).append("\n");
    buf.append(date).append("\n");
    buf.append(bucket);
    String signature = sign(buf.toString());

    // Connection to s3.amazonaws.com
    HttpURLConnection httpConn = null;
    URL url = new URL("http","s3.amazonaws.com",80,bucket);
    httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpConn.setDoInput(true);
    httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
    httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
    httpConn.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
    httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
    httpConn.setRequestMethod(method);
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Date", date);
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "0");
    String AWSAuth = "AWS " + keyId + ":" + signature;
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", AWSAuth);
    // Send the HTTP PUT request.
    int statusCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
    if ((statusCode/100) != 2)
    {
        // Deal with S3 error stream.
        InputStream in = httpConn.getErrorStream();
        String errorStr = getS3ErrorCode(in);
        System.out.println("Error: "+errorStr);
    }
      else
      {
        System.out.println("Bucket created successfully");
      }
   }

  public void setKeyId(String id)
  {
    this.keyId = id;
  }

  // This method converts AWSSecretKey into crypto instance.
  public void setKey(String AWSSecretKey) throws Exception
    {
    mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
    byte[] keyBytes = AWSSecretKey.getBytes("UTF8");
    signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "HmacSHA1");
    mac.init(signingKey);
  }

// This method creates S3 signature for a given String.
  public String sign(String data) throws Exception
  {
  // Signed String must be BASE64 encoded.
  byte[] signBytes = mac.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF8"));
  String signature = encodeBase64(signBytes);
  return signature;
  }

  public String encodeBase64(byte[] data)
  {
    String base64 =  new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encodeBuffer(data);
    if (base64.endsWith("\r\n")) base64 = base64.substring(0,base64.length()-2);
    return base64;
  }

  public String getS3ErrorCode(InputStream doc) throws Exception
  {
    String code = null;
    SAXParserFactory parserfactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    parserfactory.setNamespaceAware(false);
    parserfactory.setValidating(false);
    SAXParser xmlparser = parserfactory.newSAXParser();
    S3ErrorHandler handler = new S3ErrorHandler();
    xmlparser.parse(doc, handler);
    code = handler.getErrorCode();
    return code;
  }

// This inner class implements a SAX handler.
class S3ErrorHandler extends DefaultHandler
{
    private StringBuffer code = new StringBuffer();
    private boolean append = false;

    public void startElement(String uri, String ln, String qn, Attributes atts)
    {
        if (qn.equalsIgnoreCase("Code")) append = true;
    }

    public void endElement(String url, String ln, String qn)
    {
        if (qn.equalsIgnoreCase("Code")) append = false;
    }

    public void characters(char[] ch, int s, int length)
    {
        if (append) code.append(new String(ch, s, length));
    }

    public String getErrorCode()
    {
        return code.toString();
    }


 }
```

Comment: Show your code or full stack trace for any help.

Comment: See the edit.. I just get Access Denied. 
I print the code for it which is 403 error code.

Comment: Don't tinker with the error xml in search of just the code and message... look at the entire response body.  There's usually something valuable to be found there, when REST authentication doesn't work.

Comment: @Michael plz if u can help.. I m nt getting whats gng wrong